# Ainda é preciso restaurar Activities ao rotacionar o celular?

Tags: android

Há pouco tempo atrás, toda vez que se desenvolvia um aplicativo para Android, era preciso se preocupar com os dados que estavam na tela ao girar o celular (trocar a orientação). Conforme explicado [nesse post](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) era preciso recriar a activity.

Recentemente, ao programar, tenho notado que ao girar o celular (tanto no AVD quando no celular real) os dados não são mais destruídos. Alguém sabe dizer se mudou algo? Não é mais preciso restaurar manualmente a Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ainda é preciso, sim. O que acontece é que muitos componentes já fazem essa restauração para você automaticamente e, por isso, você não percebe. Um campo de texto pode, por exemplo, salvar o que estava escrito nele e restaurar quando a tela é recriada. Muitos componentes têm uma implementação satisfatória. Porém, quando o estado é complexo e depende da lógica da sua aplicação, não tem como fazer milagre.

Além disso, algo que é possível agora e não era antes é o uso do `setRetainInstance(true)` nos `Fragment`s, para que os mesmos não sejam destruídos durante uma mudança de configuração (no nosso caso, rotação da tela). Entretanto, isso não resolve o problema da perda de estado no caso do seu `Fragment` ser destruído pelo sistema para recuperar memória, então o melhor a se fazer é, sim, salvar e restaurar o estado você mesmo.